# Unable to format items in a ToolStripComboBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, .net-6.0

Has anyone figured out how to format items in a `ToolStripComboBox`?

This control has no `FormatString` property, but it does have a `ComboBox` property, which provides full access to the underlying `ComboBox` control.

But setting that `FormatString` has absolutely no effect.

```
tsComboBox.ComboBox.FormatString = "MMMM, yyyy";
```

I have no control over the formatting of items. Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the typical "bind a two property thing, setting one prop to be the formatted display item and the other to be the value" route:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Disp");
dt.Columns.Add("Val", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add("Hello", 1);
dt.Rows.Add("Goodbye", 2);


toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Disp";
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.ValueMember = "Val";
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = dt;
```

Then pull it with SelectedValue:

```
MessageBox.Show($"value is {toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedValue} an {toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedValue.GetType()}");
```

Doesn't have to be a datatable; `DataSource` could be e.g. a `List<KeyValuePair>`, a `List<YourClass>` etc

---

If you're looking for something more minimal you can provide something that overrides ToString:

```
    toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = 
            Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
            .Select(i => new MyX { X = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * 30) })
            .ToList();




    class MyX
    {
        public DateTime X { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() 
            => X.ToString("MMMM, yyyy"); 
    }
```

[image]